# Do we "lose" something when importing unused JS modules?

Tags: javascript, webpack, import

Apart from a little more code in the final bundle (for linking the module), do we also have any other side-effect **when importing a module but not using it** inside our code?

See image below (the 'grey' imports are not used).

Note: We are using `webpack`. Maybe webpack removes unused modules, so it is not a problem to have left-overs?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webpack remove unused modules. no need to worry about it.